# Creating New GameObject Crashes Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

This is my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System;


public class loadhospitalland : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject sidebaro;
    public GameObject bottombaro;
    public Camera hoscam;
    public Sprite plainland;
    public static float cameraheight;
    public static float camerawidth;

    public static float screenheight;
    public static float screenwidth;
    public static float screenheighta;
    public static float screenwidtha;
    public static int heightofland = 10;
    public static int widthofland = 10;
    string[,] hospitallevelone = new string[10, 10];

    public static float unitsperblockheight;
    public static float unitsperblockwidth;
    public static float unitsperblocko;
    public static float startx;
    public static float starty;
    public static float finishx;
    public static float finishy;

    public static float scalefactor;



    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        //start


        loadhosland();
    }

    private void loadhosland() {
        //calculate camera dimemsions 
        cameraheight = hoscam.orthographicSize * 2f;
        camerawidth = cameraheight * hoscam.aspect;
        print (camerawidth);
        print (cameraheight);


        //calculate the hospital area width and height by substracting the dimensions of the sidebars from the cameras dimensions
        screenheighta = (cameraheight - (bottombaro.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.bounds.size.y));
        screenwidtha = (camerawidth - (sidebaro.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite.bounds.size.x));
        //remove a 2% boarder for all sides
        screenheight = (screenheighta * 0.96f);
        screenwidth = (screenwidtha * 0.96f);
        //calculate how many units will be needed by block of land
        unitsperblockheight = (screenheight / heightofland);
        unitsperblockwidth = (screenwidth / widthofland);
        //check which width or height is smaller than use that number as you can't fit in the larger one
        if (unitsperblockwidth < unitsperblockheight) {
            unitsperblocko = unitsperblockwidth;
        } else {
            unitsperblocko = unitsperblockheight;
        }

        print ("units per block" + unitsperblocko);

        //determine scale factor for blocks
        //the scale factor is 1 when the units per blocks is 1 so the scale factor = unitsperblock
        scalefactor = unitsperblocko;
        //calculate the start x and y by calculating half of the screen and adding the border
        startx = (-1f * (hoscam.orthographicSize * hoscam.aspect)) + (0.02f*screenwidtha);
        starty = hoscam.orthographicSize - (0.02f*screenheighta);
        //calculate the finish x and y by calculating half of the screen and adding the border
        finishx = (1f * (hoscam.orthographicSize * hoscam.aspect)) - (0.02f*screenwidtha);
        finishy = (-1f * hoscam.orthographicSize) + (0.02f*screenheighta);

        print ("finishx: " + finishx + " finishy " + finishy + " startx " + startx + " starty " + starty);

        int widthon = 0;
        //int heighton = 0;



        GameObject tocreate = new GameObject ("new");

        tocreate.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();


        //GameObject toedit = GameObject.Find("new");

        //toedit.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ().sprite = plainland;

        while (widthon < widthofland) {

        }

    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
```

When I run it though, unity crashes! However, if I just use

```
GameObject tocreate = new GameObject ("new");

tocreate.AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
```

It works fine. Although if I put the above code in the start procedure of the above script, it still crashes Unity.

Can someone help? Thanks.

Comment: That's not likely the problem. Please post the complete code. If you think that's the problem, create new scene and put that code in the `Start` function(Just that code) then you will see that it's not the problem.

Comment: This is my full code

Comment: It's not that line of code. What do you mean by crash? Existed closes?

Comment: Could you provide better information on what's working and what isn't? I find it a little confusing. Also, could we get a copy of the error log? Thanks.

Comment: Pretty sure its that infinite loop at the end. widthon seems to stay 0